# How can I dim my 7" LCD touchscreen display using Raspberry OS?

Tags: raspbian, pi-3, pi-3b+, raspberry-pi-os

I have a 7" TFT LCD and I am building my own car head unit but obviously it is vital that it can dim. There are dim buttons on the board and an on/off screen button.

I have tried using:

```
echo n > /sys/class/backlight/rpi-backlight/brightness/
```

(Putting in a number between 0 and 255 for n)
however I am told that there is no such directory so I tried

```
rpi-update
```

and this did not solve the issue.
I also tried to use `ddccontrol` except it could not detect any I2C inferfaces.

I am using HDMI interface. I have attached images of my screen, the screen is capable of dimming except I can not figure out how to do this through software.

[image: Images hosted on imgur]
[image: Image hosted on imgur]

Comment: brand/model of screen would help identify if there is any software control available for the display

Comment: @JaromandaX as you wish! [link](https://www.amazon.co.uk/gp/product/B07ZD53NVQ/ref=ppx_yo_dt_b_asin_title_o05_s00?ie=UTF8&psc=1) to amazon page

Comment: @Luke, edit the question and add the info that was asked for (brand/model of screen) and NOT just a external link!